# Function working with stream of string does not work with a single string?

Tags: java, string, java-8, java-stream, predicate

Inside `MyService`, I have the following instruction that produces a semicolon-delimited string of users' emails:

```
users.stream()
     .map(UserEntity::getEmail)
     .filter(mailValidator.isValid())
     .collect(Collectors.joining(";"));
```

`MailValidator` is injected to `MyService` using Spring. This is its definition:

```
@Service
public class MailValidator {

  private final Pattern mailRegex = Pattern.compile(/** some regular expression */);

  public Predicate<String> isValid() {
    return mailRegex.asPredicate();
  }
}
```

Everything works fine. But the above `MailValidator` is not useful outside that use-case, I think.

More precisely: I am able to use `MailValidator` on a stream of strings. How can I make it work on a `String` itself, though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the signature to String argument with a boolean return

```
class MailValidator {
    private final Pattern mailRegex = Pattern.compile("");

    public boolean isValid(String s) {
        return mailRegex.matcher(s).find();
    }
}
```

and use it in your stream with a method reference:

```
users.stream()
     .map(UserEntity::getEmail)
     .filter(mailValidator::isValid)
```

Or if you are willing to compromise on the name of the method, you can make the validator implement Predicate

```
class MailValidator implements Predicate<String> {
    private final Pattern mailRegex = Pattern.compile("");

    @Override
    public boolean test(String s) {
        return mailRegex.matcher(s).find();
    }
}
```

then just do

```
users.stream()
     .map(UserEntity::getEmail)
     .filter(mailValidator)
```

Outside of this context, you would be able to call

```
 new MailValidator().test("foo")
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `isValid()` method returns some object that implements `Predicate` interface. If you check Javadocs for [Predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) it has a `test(T t)` method. All you have to do is call that method on your input String. In the end it might look like so:

```
String myStringVariable = "test";
boolean isValid = mailValidator.isValid().test(myStringVariable);
```